# Neural Network Creation in Octave

Tags: neural-network, octave

OS: Linux MINT
GNU Octave, version 7.1.0

I would like to create a neural network in Octave.

I have installed and load the following pkgs:

```
pkg list
Package Name  | Version | Installation directory
--------------+---------+-----------------------
          io *|   2.6.4 | /home/siou/snap/octave/306/.local/share/octave/api-v57/packages/io-2.6.4
       optim *|   1.6.2 | /home/siou/snap/octave/306/.local/share/octave/api-v57/packages/optim-1.6.2
  statistics *|   1.5.2 | /home/siou/snap/octave/306/.local/share/octave/api-v57/packages/statistics-1.5.2
      struct *|  1.0.18 | /home/siou/snap/octave/306/.local/share/octave/api-v57/packages/struct-1.0.18
```

However when I am trying to run:

```
net = newff(TrainingPatterns,TrainingTargets,[neurons],{'logsig'});
```

I get the following error

```
error: 'newff' undefined near line 66, column 15
error: called from
NeuralNetworkDMC at line 66 column 13
```

Comment: have you loaded the appropriate package? Also, removing a lot of the unrelated tags here – this is defintiely *not* about networking, and the fact that you want to do optimization in the end with this bears no relation to the contents of this question

Comment: The nnet package is not currently supported. See https://octave.sourceforge.io/packages.php#unmaintained-packages

Answer (score 0):

The [`newff` function](https://octave.sourceforge.io/nnet/function/newff.html) you are trying to use is part of the [`nnet` package](https://octave.sourceforge.io/nnet/index.html) which you do not have installed.

The nnet package is currently unmaintained and the last release was in 2010 so it may not work well with Octave 7 (when nnet was last release, the last Octave version was 3.2.4).  You'll have to test that yourself.  However, while there has been no new nnet release, there has been a bunch of changes on the repository over the years which is likely to work better. Both will give warnings during installation (I just tried it) but they appear innocuous. Personally, I would install from development source.

You have two options with nnet package: 1) install the last nnet release (released in 2010); 2) install the development "version" (last change was in 2019).

### (option 1) Installing the last nnet release (version 0.1.13)

Because nnet is listed as unmaintained, the command `pkg install -forge nnet` will not work. You will need to download the released tarball yourself. You can download it at [https://sourceforge.net/projects/octave/files/Octave Forge Packages/Individual Package Releases/nnet-0.1.13.tar.gz](https://sourceforge.net/projects/octave/files/Octave%20Forge%20Packages/Individual%20Package%20Releases/nnet-0.1.13.tar.gz). Once downloaded, you can install it from within Octave with:

```
# assuming it was downloaded to Downloads/
pkg install "Downloads/nnet-0.1.13.tar.gz"
```

Once installed, you will need to load the package with `pkg load nnet`

### (option 2) Installing from development source / current nnet development version

nnet package is on a mercurial repository at https://sourceforge.net/p/octave/nnet/. To clone the repository, you will need to install mercurial. You will also need GNU make. Since you're on Mint, you can do this from command line (not from within Octave).

```
apt install mercurial make
hg clone http://hg.code.sf.net/p/octave/nnet octave-nnet
cd octave-net
make install
```

Once that is done, you can start Octave and load the package with `pkg load nnet`